# Ubuntu not getting installed: Error: Kill process or sacrifice child

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb

I was trying to clean boot my pc using bootable usb & suddenly the power was off and later when I restarted my pc it was not even entering the installation mode. It is showing errors like :[this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Nd6D7wE8_acHB0U2Z1R1NENE0/view?usp=sharing)

I have already done memory & disks check( using the ones which came along with my pc by deafult ) and they all are showing passed still no installation proceeds & for either of the options - try or install errors as shown in this image are coming up.

There should not be any memory shortage as I have 8GB ram, 1tb harddisk & i5 processor. Infact, the BIOS is also showing 8GB ram only.

It is very urgent & I will be very grateful to anyone who helps me.